# How to highlight multiple items with same name in a dynamic management system

Tags: php, jquery, css

Ok, I have a backend system that watches tables update live (made in php) and i'm looking for a method where I can hover over an ID on one table and all the same IDs across tables would highlight also.

I can't have a page with just their ID as the page includes watching other live site data that needs to be watched.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: IDs need to be unique. Did you mean classes?

Comment: When you say "table" do you mean "database table" or "html table"? When you say "ID" are you talking about an id field in your database or an html element id? If you could at least show your existing html markup (or a cut-down sample of it) then we could see what you are trying to ask...

Comment: by table i mean database table & the ID i'm talking about a database field - sorry for not being clearer.  I'll make a mock up shortly to try and show the problem i'm trying to solve.

Comment: So lets say there are 3 tables displaying the ID fields of each and I hover over the ID of one of the fields in the first table (lets say i hover over ID 345) then all the other instances of that number 345 highlight on the page showing me all the 345 in any location of the page. @nnnnnn

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the HTML you're using would be helpful, but maybe something like (assume the database IDs are in TDs with a class of 'dbid')

(fair warning I did not have time to test this, but it should work or at least convey the idea)

```
$('td.dbid').hover(function() {
  id = $(this).html();
  $("td.dbid:contains('" + id + "')").css('background-color','yellow');
},
function () { 
  id = $(this).html();
  $("td.dbid:contains('" + id + "')").css('background-color','none');
});
```

Sample HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="dbid">14</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dbid">14</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dbid">13</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dbid">14</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dbid">13</td>
    <td>blah</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```